# Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long' error when printing sizes

Tags: c

Here's my code that I keep getting this error on.

```
format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long'
```

I copied the code from the lecture so I don't know what's wrong. Any help appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    double d;
    float f;
    int i;

    printf("char: %i\n", sizeof(c));
    printf("double: %i\n", sizeof(d));
    printf("float: %i\n", sizeof(f));
    printf("int: %i\n", sizeof(i));
}
```

Comment: The result of `sizeof()` is of type `size_t`, not `int`. Use `"%zi"` or cast to `(int)`.

Comment: Try `%zu` in place of `%i`.

Answer (score 9):

The results of `sizeof` operator have type `size_t`, which is an unsigned type. To print them, use `printf("%zu", ...);`.

In your case, change the `printf()` statements to

```
printf("char: %zu\n", sizeof c);
printf("double: %zu\n", sizeof d);
printf("float: %zu\n", sizeof f);
printf("int: %zu\n", sizeof i);
```

In fact, you don't need to create a variable for each type. You can just write

```
printf("char: %zu\n", sizeof (char));
printf("double: %zu\n", sizeof (double));
printf("float: %zu\n", sizeof (float));
printf("int: %zu\n", sizeof (int));
```

Also, to examine the size of `size_t` type:

```
printf("size_t: %zu\n", sizeof (size_t));
```

, which is equivalent to

```
printf("size_t: %zu\n", sizeof sizeof (char/int/float/double/...));
```